# Handling long and time consuming ajax calls in a web application with Sessions

Tags: php, web, timeout, single-page-application, background-process

Id like very much to have second thoughts on this approach Im implementing to handle very long processes in a web application.

**The problem**

I have a web application, all written in javascript, which communicates with the server via an API. This application has got some "bulk actions" that take a lot of time to execute. I want to execute them in a safe way, making sure the server won't time out, and with a rich feedback to the user, so he/she knows what is going on.

**The usual approach**

As I can see in my research, the recommended method of doing that is firing a background process in the server and make it write somewhere how its going so you can make requests to check on it and give feedback to the user. Since Im using php in the back-end, the approach would be more or less what is described here: http://humblecontributions.blogspot.com.br/2012/12/how-to-run-php-process-in-background.html

**Adding a few requisites**

Since Im developing an open source project (a WordPress plugin) I want it to work in a variety of situations and environments. I did not want to add server side requirements and, as far as I know, the background process approach may not work in several shared hosting solutions.

I want it to work out of the box, in (almost) any server with typical WordPress support, even if it ended up beeing a bit slower solution.

**My approach**

The idea is to break this process in a way it will run incrementally through many small requests.

So the first time the browser sends a request to run the process, it will run only a small step of it, and return useful information to give the user some feedback. Then the browser does another request, and repeats it until the server informs that the process is done.

In order to do this, I would store this object in a Session, so the first request will give me an id, and the following requests will send this id to the server so it will manipulate the same object.

Here is an conceptual example:

```
class LongProcess {

    function __construct() {

        $this->id = uniqid();
        $_SESSION[$this->id] = $this;
        $this->step = 1;
        $this->total = 100;

    }


    function run() {
        // do stuff based on the step you are in
        $this->step = $this->step + 10;
        if ($this->step >= $this->total)
            return -1;
        return $this->step;
    }

}

function ajax_callback() {

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_POST['id']) || empty($_POST['id'])) {
        $object = new LongProcess();
    } else {
        $object = $_SESSION[$_POST['id']];
    }

    $step = $object->run();

    echo json_encode([
        'id' => $object->id,
        'step' => $return,
        'total' => $object->total
    ]);

}
```

With this I can have my client to send requests recursivelly and update the feedback to the user as the responses are recieved.

```
    function recursively_ajax(session_id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            async:false, // set async false to wait for previous response
            url: "xxx-ajax.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{
                action: 'bulk_edit',
                id: session_id
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                updateFeedback(data);
                if(data.step != -1){
                    recursively_ajax(data.id);
                } else {
                    updateFeedback('finish');
                }
            }
        });
    }  

    $('#button').click(function() {
        recursively_ajax(); 
    });
```

Of course this is just a proof of concept, Im not even using jQuery in the actual code. This is just to express the idea.

Note that this object which is stored in the session should be a very lightweight object. Any actual data beeing processed should be stored in the database or filesystem and only reference it in the object so it knows where to look for stuff.

One typical case would be processing a large CSV file. The file would be stored in the filesystem, and the object would store a pointer to the last processed line so it knows where to start in the next request.

The object may also return a more verbose log, describing everything that was done and reporting errors, so the user have complete knowledge of what has been done.

The interface I think would be great is a progress bar with a "see details" button that would open a textarea with this detailed log.

**Does it make sense?**

So now I ask. How does it looks like? Is it a viable approach?

Is there a better way to do this and assure it will work in very limited servers?

Comment: Your description is very generic so giving advice is difficult. For example, is it necessary that the user to sit and wait for the process to finish. Could they upload the CSV file and a cronjob be run to import the CVS file straight into a db table and further manipulation takes place there? (Wordpress cronjobs are only activated it there is constant traffic to your site so you might have to set up a cronjob outside WP).

Comment: It depends how tolerant your process is to interruptions. The user can close the browser at any step of the process leaving some of the data unprocessed. If this can be tolerated, then the approach is ok.

Comment: yes, of course @Plamen and jeff, in this case the process relies on the browser so the user can not close it.

Im thinking of building it in a way that, if the server supports it, then I go to to the background process approach.

So my real question is: is this a good approach considering server limitations? or, is there other possible approach considering server limitations.

The WP_Cron could be one, since most hosting services allows you to congure a cronjob, but still not sure if it would be really better

Answer (score 2):

Your approach has several disadvantages:

1. Your heavy requests may block other requests. Usually you have a limit of concurrent PHP processes for handling web request. If the limit is 10, and all slots are taken by processing your heavy requests, your website will not work until some of these requests will complete releasing slot for another lightweight request.
2. You (probably) will not be able to estimate how much time will take to finish one step. Depending on server load it could take 5 or 50 seconds. And 50 second will probably exceed time execution limit on most of shared hostings.
3. This task will be controlled by client - any interruption from client side (network problems, closing browser tab) will interrupt the task.
4. Depending on session backend, using session for storing current state may result in race condition bugs - concurrent request from the same client may overwrite changes in session done by background task. By default PHP uses locking for session, so this should not be the case, but if someone uses alternative backend for sessions (DB, redis) without locking, this will result serious and hard to debug bugs.

There is an obvious trade-off here. For small websites where simplifying installation and configuration is a priority, your approach is OK. In any other case I would stick to simple cron-based queue for running tasks in background and use AJAX request only to retrieve current status of task. So far I have not seen hosting without cron support and adding task to cron should not be that hard for the end user (with proper documentation).

In both cases I would not use session as a storage. Save task and its status in database and use some locking system to ensure, that only one process can modify data of one task. This will be really much more robust and flexible than using session.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input. I just want to document here some very good answers I got.

Some WordPress plugins, named Woocommerce, have incorporated code from "WP Background Processing" library, that is no longer mantained, but that implements the Cron approach with some important improvements. See this blog post:

https://deliciousbrains.com/background-processing-wordpress/

The actual library lives here: https://github.com/A5hleyRich/wp-background-processing

Although this is a WordPress specific library, I think the approach is valid for any situation.

There is also, for WordPress, a library called Action Scheduler, that not only tun proccesses in background, but allows you to schedule them. Its worth a look:

https://github.com/Prospress/action-scheduler